# c# - folderBrowserDialog1 and Network Drive

Tags: c#, special-folders, folderbrowserdialog

Is there anyway to set the folderBrowserDialog to start in a set folder on a network drive? I know it takes Environment.SpecialFolders but I'm not seeing what I need in there...

Comment: SpecialFolders only describes *local* folders.  Figuring out what the folder should be for a network share is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `SelectedPath` to a path on the network.

I don't think it's possible to a folder picker *rooted* to a network path.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, the FolderBrowserDialog should start with a specific folder already selected, then set the SelectedPath property before calling ShowDialog.

If you mean rooted to a specific folder, the FolderBrowserDialog can only be rooted to one of the SpecialFolders values.

Alternately, use a control like [FolderView](http://www.ssware.com/fldrview.htm) which allows rooting to a random folder. Further, its a control, so you can place it in your own form.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developers of FolderView.